# Get user ID from phonegap facebook login

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

I am trying to allow a user to upload photos to my server after they login to my system with their facebook credentials.  I am using the phonegap facebook plugin for android.  How can I get their unique user ID from the facebook SDK?  And should I use the javascript SDK or the Android SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after u call FB.init....u have to call FB.login function and in the response of fb.login u will get the user id of person logged in...

the code for FB.login is

```
FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    alert('logged in');
                    fbId = response.authResponse.userId;
                     alert("user id is "+fbId);
                } else {
                    alert('not logged in');
                }
            }, {
                scope : "email"
            });
```

Comment: your solution is obselete.. clifgray is more correct

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is curious this is how you do it after initializing the facebook javascript SDK:

```
FB.api('/me', function(me){
        if (me.id) {
            var facebook_userid = me.id;
            alert(facebook_userid);
        }
    });
```